# Irreducibility of $R$ and $\operatorname{Spec}(R)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

If $R$ is an irreducible ring, is $\operatorname{Spec}(R)$ an irreducible topological space? Is the converse true?

A ring $R$ is said to be irreducible if whenever $I$ and $J$ are ideals of $R$ such that $I \cap J=0$, then $I=0$ or $J=0$.

I'm quite sure this has already been asked but I can't find the question

Comment: Which definition for irreducible ring are you using? You can check that $\mathrm{Spec}\,R$ is an irreducible topological space iff the ideal of nilpotents of $R$ is prime.

Comment: @Mindlack I am aware of that criterion, but I am asking for something different. I edited the question.

Comment: For reduced rings the notions are equivalent. But there are nonreduced non-irreducible rings with irreducible spectra, such as $R=\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2,10x)$: the ideals $(10,5x)$ and $(2x)$ do not have any nonzero common element but $R_{red}$ is a domain so the spectrum of $R$ is irreducible. I’m not sure of the other implication but I think it’s false too.

Comment: @Mindlack Do you have a reference for the equivalence in the case of reduced rings? It seems plausible to me that we could have a reduced ring with infinitely many minimal primes (hence Spec is not irreducible) but such that no finite intersection of minimal primes is $0$, and such a ring could be irreducible.

Comment: @Alex Kruckman: let $R$ be a reduced irreducible ring. Let $a,b \in R$ be nonzero, then there are $x,y \in R$ such that $ax=by$ is nonzero. So $abxy=(ax)^2 \neq 0$ so $ab \neq 0$, so $R$ is an integral domain. Conversely, if $R$ is an integral domain (ie reduced with irreducible spectrum) and $I,J$ are nonzero ideals, $IJ$ is a nonzero ideal contained in $I \cap J$ so $R$ is irreducible.

Comment: @Mindlack Nice, thanks. You should make an answer out of the argument you just gave, plus the counterexample you gave above to equivalence for non-reduced rings.